# The derivative of y with respect to y

Tags: derivatives

I have this equation:

$$y = \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{2}}$$

and the answer given is:

$$\frac{d}{dy} = \Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3x^2}\Bigg)\frac{d}{dx}$$

Can someone please explain me how this is done ??

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Now this actually is highly informal, but using the chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d}{dy}=\frac{3x^2}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{d}{dy}$$
So
$$\frac{d}{dy}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3x^2}\frac{d}{dx}$$

Comment: that was very helpful